# Cancel ProgressDialog after running between dialogs

Tags: android, timer, dialog, progressdialog

I'm trying to mock up a USSD interaction in Android by creating a series of dialog menus that you can go through in Android. Right now, (thanks to a user who helped me [on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231859/show-progressdialog-between-dialogs)!) I have it so that in between dialogs, there is a progress dialog that says "USSD code running..." that runs for 2 seconds between each dialog. Now, though, my problem is that I cannot cancel the progress dialog after it has run. Now, when I have finished going through dialogs, there are several instances of the progress dialog that are still open and running. I know that I need to include the progress.cancel() command in the code somewhere, but each place I try it in seems to prevent the progress dialog from running it all.

```
Runnable progressRunnable;

public void FirstScreen() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog; pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.number_response_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(dialogView)
            .setMessage(R.string.MainMenuText)
                    // Add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.send, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Send number to next dialog
                    String choice = getMenuChoice(dialogView);
                    if (choice.equals("5")) {
                        //Go to FirstTimeUse menu
                        progressRunnable = new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                FirstTimeUse();
                            }
                        };
                        USSDprogressDialog(progressRunnable);
                    } else if (choice.equals("6")) {
                        //Something else
                    } else {
                        //Do nothing
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // End session
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

And the actual progress dialog helper method:

```
public void USSDprogressDialog(Runnable runnable) {
    final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setMessage("USSD code running...");
    progress.show();

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
}
```

I tried including at the end of the USSDProgressDialog method as well as inside all the dialogs when USSDProgressDialog is run. Where else can I include it so that it will cancel each time after the timer runs out? Thank you!

Comment: Which timer you're indicating to?

Comment: It's the one that is in the USSDProgressDialog method, the handler that delays the runnable for 2 seconds at the end. (It's not an actual "timer" but it works)

Answer (score 0):

```
final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
```

You need to put the declaration of the progress dialogue outside of the `USSDprogressDialog` function so that it can be accessed from all other functions of the activity. Initialize the progress dialogue globally.

Now from the positive button's `onClickListener` try using this example code.

```
if (choice.equals("5")) {
    //Go to FirstTimeUse menu
    progressRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            FirstTimeUse();
            // Now cancel the progress dialog here. 
            if(progress != null) progress.cancel();
        }
    };

    USSDprogressDialog(progressRunnable);
}
```